# How do I update my old date in every 14 days automatically to show 14 days of income in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

### **This is my little bit code**

```
  const seller = await Seller.findOne({seller: req.seller.id});
  const joinUpdate = seller.createdAt
  const nowDate = new Date(joinUpdate);
  const Month = new Date(nowDate.setDate(nowDate.getDate() + 14));
  console.log(nowDate.toLocaleString())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write cronjobs to schedule tasks.
Explore [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)

Comment: how ?  Can you tell me little bit about it?

Comment: You can create a function which updates the date or whatever else you need, and then schedule to run it every 14 days at anytime, like for instance every 2 weeks at Sunday by
`cron.schedule('0 2 */14 * *', yourFunction)`
play with your time [here](https://crontab.guru/)